# Is this question sufficiently different from this other question to warrant posting?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question

Is Question 1 sufficiently different from Question 2 to warrant posting Question 1?:

1. "If I am given N congruent circles with radii R, and they are equidistantly spaced upon a sphere, can I figure out if the sphere's covered?"
2. ["What is the minimum radius of N congruent circles that are placed on a sphere equidistant from each other, so that the sphere is covered by circles?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386042/minimum-radius-radii-range-of-such-for-n-equally-sized-circles-on-a-sphere-eq)

I intended Question 2 to answer the question of: "How wide a radius of a field do I need 10,000 field emitters to emit, so the total field covers the Earth", but since the latter question can't seem to solve that problem... I've got to change the question... so I turned in on its head, I think...

Comment: There's a better way to format this... I think... But I don't know it...

Comment: Most definitely. Please consider providing your question with [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960/43351).

Comment: @Lord_Farin - Well, is that context? Or should I just change my existing question?

Comment: Certainly, that should be sufficient. If you include a link to the previous question with this explanation, all should be fine.

Comment: @Lord_Farin - Oh! So your "Most definitely" was in response to the question of sufficient difference, instead of the question of better formatting, which I had assumed... Well, it seems to have worked out...

Comment: Ah, I see the misunderstanding now :).

Comment: @Lord_Farin - So I shouldn't have posted the question?

Comment: As to the end of all unclarity, your new question is fine and asking this question on meta was also fine.